# Moving between two fragments failed: No View for Id test found

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to move from one Fragment to my seccond Fragment with the following code:

```
fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Geklickt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Fragment fragment = new Map();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.test,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Here is the layout file for my seccond fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/test"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"/>
```

and the Class code from my seccond fragment:

```
ublic class Map extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
return rootView;
}
```

Unfortunately i get always the following error Message if i try to switch between my Fragments:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00b0 (com.example.hartl.pxp:id/test) for fragment Map{2ffde30 #3 id=0x7f0d00b0}
```

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.test,fragment);  Use your container's view id in which you want to replace fragment.

Comment: what do you mean with container view

Comment: Container view like frame layout or view pager, where you add your fragments. Fragments are added in container view

Comment: So I should add  in my second layout a framelayout?

Comment: Suppose your activity have framelayout. It will consider as container. And you have to add your fragments inside that framelayout. Currently you are directly adding layout's id to the fragment transaction, which is not correct way

Comment: No I did it different I created a tab project and added for every tab its own fragment class and a layout for that now I would   add a new fragment with its own layout like the other ones before therefore I have no activity which contains my framelayouts